# Angular 7, while trying to directly copy and access the internal page link into chrome through "Maximum call stack size exceeded error"

Tags: google-chrome, stack, max, angular7, call

Thanks in advance. I am new in angular7. when i right click on some of internal link and choose 'Open in new tab' - Chrome shows error "Maximum call stack error" 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsG2v.png)
Firefox through error : 'InternalError: "too much recursion"'

But Microsoft Edge is working fine.

I found in debugging time, the browser through error before it hit that linked component.

[My English is very poor. please ignore it].

Please give me a guideline to solve this.
Thank you

Comment: Please avoid using your site's link as it can seem promotive.
Adding code to your question can help you find answers sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing lots of static pages and their routes from app.routing. Mainly lots of routes cause memory full for Google Chrome and Firefox but not for Microsoft Edge because it's memory stack is larger then two others.